# Mgento Admin Grid Multi select "," seperated value filter not working in custom grid Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, grid, filter

I create custom grid that include Website field and customer group fields are multiselect.
At Filter apply also need to set as multiselect that not working for me.

here I share my listing xml file code

```
<column name="website" class="Extension\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Extension\Module\Model\Source\Websites</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">Meetanshi\Msg\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Multiselect</item>
                    <item name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Extension\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Multiselect</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Website</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

The customer group and website ids store as , separated value in data base.
[image]
Screen Shoot :::  https://prnt.sc/9uy1BOt4Vi00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; 
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 's_id';
    
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
      //  StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_init(
            'Vendor\Module\Model\Module',
            'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module'
        );
        //Class naming structure 
        // 'NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\ModelName', 'NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName'
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        //$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
}
```

Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection as GridCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
/**
 * Class Collection
 * Collection for displaying grid
 */
class Collection extends GridCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     * @param EntityFactoryInterface   $entityFactory,
     * @param LoggerInterface          $logger,
     * @param FetchStrategyInterface   $fetchStrategy,
     * @param ManagerInterface         $eventManager,
     * @param StoreManagerInterface    $storeManager,
     * @param String                   $mainTable,
     * @param String                   $eventPrefix,
     * @param String                   $eventObject,
     * @param String                   $resourceModel,
     * @param $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
     * @param $connection = null,
     * @param AbstractDb              $resource = null
     * @return $this
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        //StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
          //  $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }
    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }
    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null
    ) {
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }
    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     *
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'store_id') {
            $conditionSec = ['like' => '%'.$condition['eq'].'%'];
            return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $conditionSec);
        }
        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).